# How to use wget to cache your website pages and mobiles pages

Tags: wget

so i have found you can use this line

wget --cache=off --delete-after -m https://url.com

but if my website has different pages for mobile how would i emulate a mobile using wget to cache mobile pages

Answer (score 2):

> but if my website has different pages for mobile how would i emulate a mobile

Try using a user agent that looks like it's from a mobile browser.

```
wget --user-agent=”User Agent Here” “[URL]”
```

A list of user agent strings you can try is here: https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings - or you can find out the user agent the browser on your phone uses by putting "What's my user agent" from the Google search website.